# Question closed with no feedback for improvement; how can I improve the question?

Tags: discussion

My post [Drive setup for Time Machine and file sharing connected to router](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470958/drive-setup-for-time-machine-and-file-sharing-connected-to-router) was closed for being opinion-based. That's fine; I can accept that. None of the five users who voted to close the question offered any feedback as to how to improve the post/question.

What improvements can I make to the post to edit and reopen?

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, this seems to be a „what is the best …“ question. These questions tend to lead to answers based on opinions and individual taste, because „best“ is different for different people. Also, if you look at the comments, it seems that people doubt that the approach will work at all.

To get answers based on facts, you would need to focus on the problem to be solved and list the criteria relevant for you first. Usually, once the criteria are listed, you can evaluate the options yourself or ask specific questions about their feasibility.